# Adding multi dimensional array to database in PHP

Tags: php

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Heart Choclates [code] => LFB-P-10 [qty] => 1 [type] => main [price] => 1200 [stock] => 5 [image] => choclates-valentines-day.jpg [quantity] => 12 [expdate] => May 27th 2017 [exptime] => 11:00 PM to 12:00 AM [expdtype] => Mid night delivery ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Birthday Pink [code] => KB-P-5 [qty] => 1 [type] => addon [price] => 600 [stock] => 7 [image] => pink-roses.jpg [expdate] => May 27th 2017 [exptime] => 11:00 PM to 12:00 AM [expdtype] => Mid night delivery ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Red & Yellow Roses [code] => KB-P-6 [qty] => 1 [type] => main [price] => 800 [stock] => 9 [image] => birthday-red-roses.jpg [expdate] => May 27th 2017 [exptime] => 11:00 PM to 12:00 AM [expdtype] => Mid night delivery ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Signature Cake [code] => KB-P-7 [qty] => 1 [type] => addon [price] => 0 [stock] => 9 [image] => signature-cake.jpg [expdate] => May 27th 2017 [exptime] => 11:00 PM to 12:00 AM [expdtype] => Mid night delivery ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Truffle Cake [code] => KB-P-8 [qty] => 1 [type] => addon [price] => 10 [stock] => 7 [image] => truffle-cake.jpg [expdate] => May 27th 2017 [exptime] => 11:00 PM to 12:00 AM [expdtype] => Mid night delivery ) ) )
```

I have an array like this.. an array of orders and array of products inside each array of orders. Now i need to add these arrays into database with orders in each row and products seprated by a `<br/>` . How is it possible? Thanks in advance.

I used this for each to print the code.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    print_r($_SESSION["products"]);
    foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $row => $temp){    
?>                                        
<div>
<?php
   foreach($temp as $innerRow => $cart_itm){
    ?>
        <div><?php echo $cart_itm['code']; ?></div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Expecting this Result

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do u mean by "```Now i need to add these arrays into database with orders in each row and products seprated by a``` "?

Comment: sorry that break was missing.Edited just now

Comment: again what u mean by ```products seprated by a <br/>```? can u give any example of your expected output?

Comment: product name 1 <br/> product name 2 <br/> .Like this so i can explode and get the products

Comment: @SarathHari Your question isn't clear to me! If you could rephrase your question providing sample output, it would help us to give you a better solution.

Comment: @SarathHari So now according to your expecting result, there are basically  4 rows in the table.  Two rows with Order Id 1001 & another two rows with Order ID 1002. Right!!! or it's only 2 rows in the table? I'm in confusion.

Comment: Again, your answer is confusing. Your expected result which you have shown that's having 4 rows or 2 rows? Describe it properly.

Comment: There are only two rows 1001 and 1002 . and product are nothing but sub arrays Orders 1001 consist of two products 1 and 2 from Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [product1],  [1] => Array ( [product2]))

Comment: Only two rows 1001 and 1002

Comment: is it clear for you now ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will get you started:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        array(
            'name'  => 'Heart Choclates',
            'code'  => 'LFB-P-10',
            'qty'   => '1' 
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => 'Birthday Pink',
            'code'  => 'KB-P-5',
            'qty'   => '1' 
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'name'  => 'Red & Yellow Roses',
            'code'  => 'KB-P-6',
            'qty'   => '1'
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => 'Signature Cake',
            'code'  => 'KB-P-7',
            'qty'   => '1'
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => 'Truffle Cake',
            'code'  => 'KB-P-8',
            'qty'   => '1'
        )
    )
);

foreach( $data as $row_item )
{
    $row = array();

    foreach( $row_item as $product )
    {
        foreach( $product as $key => $value )   
        {
            if( isset( $row[ $key ] ) )
                $row[ $key ] .= $value . ' <br> ';
            else
                $row[ $key ] = $value . ' <br> ';        
        }
    }

    //--- 
    echo 'Row: <br>';
    var_dump( $row );
    echo '<br><br>';

    //-- insert the contents of $row array into the database
}
```

Output:

[image]

You can insert the contents of `$row` array into database.

---

**EDIT**

Please note that, the above answer is based on your specific question that you asked.

I still didn't understood what exactly you are doing here. If you are trying to store the details of an order, then this is a poor method of accomplishing it! You should keep separate database table and use a relationship to join together. This is what a relational database is for!

For example, let the two tables be `tblOrderMaster` and `tblOrderDetails`.

Here, in the `tblOrderMaster` table, the primary key will be the `order_id` and you would probably gonna store the total amount, discount amount, total service tax, order date, customer id, order status, etc.

And in the `tblOrderDetails` table, you are gonna have several rows, in which we are gonna store each products of a particular order. For example, it will store order id (foreign key), product id, unit price, quantity, tax, total (unit_price x quantity), etc..

This would be the proper way, I believe.

Comment: still how it ill be added to database

Comment: The data will be available in that `$row` variable. Just insert the data present in that array, into your database!

Comment: I am not able to add to database . but i am able to print it. I updated my question with a screenshot of database

Comment: What datatype are you using for those database fields? Are they `varchar` ? If you are using `int`, `decimal`, etc for some of the fields(like quantity, etc.) the data will not be stored properly! As you wanted to include `<br>` in the field values!!

Comment: No datatypes are proper. But where can i show you my code sample !

Comment: See if there's any error is generated while you are trying to do the insertion into database.

Comment: Even i still believe the same but i am re editing an existing website in limited time. There is no other solutions. Even flipkart or any other eccomerce website have this kind of requirements i believe

Comment: thanks it worked .. The code was using Update because in previous page adress is added already

Answer (score 2):

Try this sample code.

```
    $orderList[1001] = array(
        0 => array(
                'name' => 'Heart Choclates',
                'code' => 'LFB-P-10',
                'qty' => 1,
                'type' => 'main',
                'price' => 1200,
                'stock' => 5,
                'image' => 'choclates-valentines-day.jpg',
                'quantity' => 12,
                'expdate' => 'May 27th 2017',
                'exptime' => '11:00 PM to 12:00 AM',
                'expdtype' => 'Mid night delivery'
            ),
        1 => array(
                'name' => 'Birthday Pink',
                'code' => 'KB-P-5',
                'qty' => 1,
                'type' => 'addon',
                'price' => 600,
                'stock' => 7,
                'image' => 'pink-roses.jpg',
                'quantity' => 3,
                'expdate' => 'May 27th 2017',
                'exptime' => '11:00 PM to 12:00 AM',
                'expdtype' => 'Mid night delivery'
            )
    );

$orderList[1002] = array(
        0 => array(
                'name' => 'Red & Yellow Roses',
                'code' => 'KB-P-6',
                'qty' => 1,
                'type' => 'main',
                'price' => 800,
                'stock' => 9,
                'image' => 'birthday-red-roses.jpg',
                'quantity' => 10,
                'expdate' => 'May 27th 2017',
                'exptime' => '11:00 PM to 12:00 AM',
                'expdtype' => 'Mid night delivery'
            )
    );


echo '<pre>';
print_r($orderList);
echo '<pre>';

$productList = array();

foreach ($orderList as $key => $value)
{
    $names = array();
    $quantity = array();

    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        $names[] = $value1['name'];
        $quantity[] = $value1['quantity'];
    }

    $productList[$key]['names'] = implode('<br>', $names);  // Used `:` insted of '<br>' for separator. But, You can use whatever you want. But, better don't use any HTML tag.
    $productList[$key]['quantity'] = implode('<br>', $quantity);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($productList);
echo '<pre>';


// Sample DATA INSERTION Query by PDO
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbproductName=someDatabase', $userproductName, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Prepare the query ONCE
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO someTable VALUES(:name, :quantity)');

    foreach ($productList as $key => $value) {
        $productName = $value['names'];
        $productQuantity = $value['quantity'];

        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $productName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $productQuantity);

        $stmt->execute();
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Ref : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338
```

Comment: I am asking how to add this to database as different row of orders.I am able to print it

Comment: As the output is in form of an array, you can use that array in any loop & make your insert query accordingly to insert them in your DB. How difficult is that?

Comment: @SarathHari added a sample PDO query for insertion at bottom of the code sample. Check that for reference if you are facing any problem in inserting records from that data array.

Comment: updated my question please see whats my expectation. Thank you for giving your time.I am not much experienced in php. Just 4 months and i am from mechanical backgound

Comment: Ha ha, that's why little information always dangerous :D

Comment: I need to complete my project today.Part of the job :(

Comment: @SarathHari updated my code above. Hope that will help you.